# Trying to fetch local SQL Server details from Windows server using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, registry

Trying to fetch local SQL Server details using PowerShell in below format.

```
Name                           Value                                                    
----                           -----                                                    
Instance                       MSSQLServer                                              
InstanceNameFullName           MSSQL11.MSSQLServer                                          
Version                        11.0.3000.0                                              
Edition                        Standard Edition                                         
MajorVersion                   SQL Server 2012
```

I am trying to fetch `MajorVersion` using query, but It couldn't fetch the SQL details for multiple named instance on one SQL Server instance.

This is my code - I hope it will help you:

```
function ListSQLInstances {
    $listinstances = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    #registry
    $installedInstances = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQLServer').InstalledInstances
    foreach ($i in $installedInstances) {
    $instancefullname = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i
    $productversion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$instancefullname\Setup").Version


    # Getting the SQL SERVER 20XX value
    $trimmedVersion  = Invoke-SqlCmd -query "select @@version"
    $fullVersion = $trimmedVersion.Column1
    $MajorVersion = $fullVersion.Substring(10, 16)

    # Adding SQL server data to a custom object___
    $instance = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Instance             = $i
        InstanceNameFullName = $instancefullname;
        Edition              = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$instancefullname\Setup").Edition;
        Version              = $productversion;
        MajorVersion         = $MajorVersion;
    }
    $listinstances.Add($instance)
}
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple instances on one SQL Server.  Multiple SQL Server instances can be installed on the same Windows Machine.  But one instance cannot have multiple instances.

Comment: yes but how can I run query on multiple SQL Server intsances using powershell.

Comment: You need to cluster the servers : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1541/getting-started-with-sql-server-clustering/?force_isolation=true

Comment: "but It couldn't fetch the SQL details for multiple named instance on one SQL Server instance" - why not? Were there any errors? You are going to need to provide some details if we are going to have a chance at helping you.